# railsAutocomplete.select not working when option is selected throgh down arrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am using rails3-jquery-autocomplete for autocomplete functionality but when I select through mouse autocomplete works but if I select through keyboard down and arrow and click enter its not working I am having following code. What I am missing

```
  $(".text_field_title").live("focusout",function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var value = $(this).val();
    var activity_id = $(this).attr("rel")
    var practice_plan_id = $(this).attr('practice_plan_id');

    $("#"+activity_id+"_title").bind('railsAutocomplete.select',function(event,data){
      var data = [
        {
          name : name,
          value : value
        },
        {
          name : "activity_id",
          value : activity_id
        },
        {
          name :"fav_id",
          value : data.item.id
        }
      ];

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl',
        data: data,
        dataType: "script"
      });

    });
});
```